# Ext JS: How to maintain hierarchy of fields when submitting form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extjs

I need to make a workflow of kind as shown in image below. This workflow have tasks with hierarchy of
sub tasks

[image]

My model is of kind

```
public class WorkflowTaskDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<TaskDTO> TaskDTOList { get; set; }
}

public class TaskDTO
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int TaskOrder { get; set; }
    public List<TaskDTO> TaskDTOList { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

My application is in extjs, so i have designed a form as shown in image below:

[image]

Now, the problem is when I submit my form, it post the data in the form of array which does not indicate the hierarchy of the tasks i.e. relation of child and parent, which sub task belongs to which tasks.

[image]

My extjs code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="Ext/build/packages/ext-theme-neptune/build/resources/ext-theme-neptune-all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Ext/build/ext-all.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.define('Ext.form.ClosableFieldSet', {
                extend: 'Ext.form.FieldSet',
                alias: 'widget.workflowClosableFieldSet',
                columnWidth: 0.5,
                title: 'Workflow',
                collapsible: true,
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                defaults: { anchor: '100%' },
                layout: 'anchor',
                items: [
                    {
                        fieldLabel: 'Task Name',
                        name: 'TaskName'
                    },
                    {
                        fieldLabel: 'Description',
                        name: 'field2'
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'remove',
                        style: 'float: right; width: 120px ! important;',
                        handler: function (btn) {
                            console.log(this.counter);
                            var fieldset = btn.up('fieldset');
                            var fieldsetId = fieldset.getId();
                            Ext.getCmp(fieldsetId).destroy();
                        }
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        text: 'Add SubTask',
                        style: 'float: right; width: 120px ! important;',
                        handler: function () {
                            console.log(this.counter);
                            this.up('fieldset').add(Ext.widget('workflowClosableFieldSet', {
                            }));
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
            Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                title: 'Form with Dynamic FieldSets',
                bodyPadding: 10,
                width: 550,
                renderTo: 'output',

                items: [
               {
                   xtype: 'textfield',
                   name: 'WorkflowName',
                   fieldLabel: 'Workflow Name:'
               }, {
                   xtype: 'button',
                   text: 'Add Task',
                   handler: function () {
                       this.up('form').add(Ext.widget('workflowClosableFieldSet', {
                       }));
                   }
               },
                {
                    xtype: 'workflowClosableFieldSet'
                }
                ],
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Reset',
                    handler: function () {
                        this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                    }
                }, {
                    text: 'Submit',
                    formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid
                    disabled: true,
                    handler: function () {
                        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                        console.log(form);
                        console.log(form.getValues());
                        console.log(form.getValues());
                        if (form.isValid()) {
                            form.submit({
                                success: function (form, action) {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
                                },
                                failure: function (form, action) {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }]
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

is there any way to maintain such hierarchy using extjs while submitting form.

Comment: There are a number of deficiencies in your question. 1.) There is absolutely no description of the problem that you are encountering. 2.) Your code is very poorly formatted. 3.) Your code is not specific enough (e.g., highlighting the areas where the problem is). So if you hope to get an answer to this question, I would start by articulating the problem you're having, paring down the code to the relevant parts for the issue, and (if possible) provide a runnable version of your code to that others can help debug whatever the problem might be.

Comment: I think now the problem is pretty much clear. So, is there any solution or suggestion to this problem?

Comment: Yes, I am able to submit my data to server and save in database. Thanks. But now the problem is, how to show such data with same hierarchies in extjs grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In submit click

```
{
    text: 'Submit',
    formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid
    disabled: true,
    handler: function () {
        var form = this.up('form');
        console.log(form);
        var WorkflowTaskDTO = {
            Name: '',
            Remarks: '',
            TaskDTOList: []
        }
        var array = form.items.items;
        //console.log(array.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            switch (array[i].componentCls) {
                case 'x-field':
                    switch (array[i].name) {
                        case 'WorkflowName':
                            WorkflowTaskDTO.Name = array[i].value;
                            break;
                        case 'Remarks':
                            WorkflowTaskDTO.Remarks = array[i].value;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;


                case 'x-fieldset':
                    var __ = this.customFunction(array[i]);
                    WorkflowTaskDTO.TaskDTOList.push(__);
                    break;
            }
        }

        console.log(WorkflowTaskDTO);

        if (form.isValid()) {

            Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: '/Workflow/Create',
                type: 'json',
                method: 'POST',
                jsonData: WorkflowTaskDTO,
                success: function (response) {


                },
                failure: function (response) {

                }
            });
        }
    },
    customFunction: function (item) {
        var TaskDTO = {
            Name: '',
            TaskOrder: '',
            DesignationAssignedTo: '',
            DesignationAssignedBy: '',
            DesignationApprovedBy: '',
            Remarks: '',
            IsProcessComplete: '',
            IsBrainStromingRequired: '',
            IsTaskActivityRequired: '',
            IsUploadRequired: '',
            IsApproveRequired: '',
            TaskDTOList: []
        }
        var array = item.items.items;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            switch (array[i].componentCls) {
                case 'x-field':
                    switch (array[i].name) {
                        case 'TaskName':
                            TaskDTO.Name = array[i].value;
                            break;
                        case 'TaskOrder':
                            TaskDTO.TaskOrder = array[i].value;
                            break;
                        case 'DesignationAssignedTo':
                            TaskDTO.DesignationAssignedTo = array[i].value;
                            break;
                        case 'DesignationAssignedBy':
                            TaskDTO.DesignationAssignedBy = array[i].value;
                            break;
                        case 'DesignationApprovedBy':
                            TaskDTO.DesignationApprovedBy = array[i].value;
                            break;
                        case 'Remarks':
                            TaskDTO.Remarks = array[i].value;
                            break;
                        case 'IsProcessComplete':
                            TaskDTO.IsProcessComplete = array[i].value;
                            break;
                        case 'IsBrainStromingRequired':
                            TaskDTO.IsBrainStromingRequired = array[i].value;
                            break;
                        case 'IsTaskActivityRequired':
                            TaskDTO.IsTaskActivityRequired = array[i].value;
                            break;
                        case 'IsUploadRequired':
                            TaskDTO.IsUploadRequired = array[i].value;
                            break
                        case 'IsApproveRequired':
                            TaskDTO.IsApproveRequired = array[i].value;
                            break;
                    }
                    break;

                case 'x-fieldset':
                    var __ = this.customFunction(array[i]);
                    TaskDTO.TaskDTOList.push(__);
                    break;

            }
        }

        return TaskDTO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, Ext JS doesn't treat form values hierarchically. While you might be creating hierarchies in terms of components, the actual values of form fields is going to be flattened into the form that you're currently seeing in your results.

In order to submit this data in a hierarchy that matches what you're creating in terms of interface, you'll need to create your own serialization process. You could do this in a number of ways. For example:

- Start from the form and traverse the descendant tree for each
  fieldset, building out your value hierarchy as you go
- Create some naming convention on the fields and use `getFieldValues()`
  to get a key/value list of all values. Then you could recursively
  analyze that list to build out the hierarchy based on your naming
  convention.

Neither of these methods (or something else) should be too hard to do, but you will have to create your own serialization of the data in order to submit in in the way you want.